# Фильтр на JavaScript с активным checkbox

Tags: javascript

Реализую фильт. При 8+ активных checkbox появляется поле поиска, а активные checkbox поднимаются вверх.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функционал фильтра?

У меня не выходит разобраться с двумя моментами:

1. При клике на checkbox хочу сделать чтобы добалялось/убиралось значение в счетчике(сейчас только добавляется);
2. Если мы кликаем по элементу сheckbox он поднимается в самый верх списка, если галку убираем соответственно перемещается на прежнее место.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let clickDiv = document.getElementById("click-div");
  clickDiv.onclick = incrementClick;

  let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-button");
  resetBtn.onclick = resetCounter;
}

var counterVal = 0;

incrementClick = function() {
  updateDisplay(++counterVal);
}


function resetCounter() {
  counterVal = 0;
  updateDisplay(counterVal);
}

function updateDisplay(val) {
  document.getElementById("counter-label").innerHTML = val;
  if (counterVal >= 8) {
    document.getElementById("search_id").style.display = "block";
  } else if (counterVal <= 8) {
    document.getElementById("search_id").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
  .search_id {
  display: none;
}

#click-div input {
  display: block;
}

#click-div span {
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <center>JavaScript Click Counter</center>
</h3>
<div>
  <input id="search_id" type="поиск">
  <center>
    <h3 id="counter-label">0</h3>
  </center>
</div>
<center>
  <div>
    <div id="click-div">
      <input type="checkbox">A</input>
      <input type="checkbox">B</input>
      <input type="checkbox">C</input>
      <input type="checkbox">D</input>
      <input type="checkbox">E</input>
      <input type="checkbox">T</input>
      <input type="checkbox">Y</input>
      <input type="checkbox">U</input>
      <input type="checkbox">I</input>
    </div>
    <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или такой вот вариант:

```js
((w, d) => {
  class Filter {
    filterBox = d.getElementById('click-div');

    checkAll = [];
    allow = [];
    disallow = [];

    counterNode;
    searchNode

    constructor(idRoot) {
      this.filterBox = d.getElementById(idRoot);
      if (!this.filterBox)
        throw new Error("Не найдено... Ошибка, ошибка, ошибка... o_O");

      this.counterNode = d.getElementById('counter-label');
      this.searchNode = d.getElementById('search_id');
      this
        .setEventCheck()
        .setEventReset();
    }

    setEventCheck() {
      this.filterBox.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((el, key) => {
        let checkEl = { initRange: key, node: el };

        this.checkAll.push(checkEl);
        this.toggleFilterItem(checkEl);
        el.onchange = this.toggleFilterItem.bind(this, checkEl, false);
      });

      this.rangeFilterItem();
      return this;
    }

    setEventReset() {
      this.filterBox.onreset = () => {
        this.checkAll.forEach(checkEl => {
          this.toggleFilterItem(checkEl, true);
        });
      };
      return this;
    }

    toggleFilterItem(checkEl, off = false) {
      if (checkEl.node.checked && !off) {
        delete this.disallow[checkEl.initRange];
        this.allow[checkEl.initRange] = checkEl.node;
      } else {
        delete this.allow[checkEl.initRange];
        this.disallow[checkEl.initRange] = checkEl.node;
      }

      this.rangeFilterItem();
    }

    toggleSearch(show) {
      if (show)
        this.searchNode.classList.remove('search_hide');
      else
        this.searchNode.classList.add('search_hide');
    }

    changeCountAllow(count) {
      this.counterNode.innerText = count;

      return this;
    }

    rangeFilterItem() {
      let count = 0;

      this.allow.forEach(el => {
        el.parentElement.style.order = ++count;
      });

      this.changeCountAllow(count);
      this.toggleSearch(count == this.checkAll.length);

      this.disallow.forEach(el => {
        el.parentElement.style.order = ++count;
      });

      return this;
    }
  }

  d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const filter = new Filter('click-div');

  });
})(window, document);
```

```css
  .search_hide {
  display: none;
}

#click-div span {
  display: inline-block;
}

#click-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h3>
<center>JavaScript Click Counter</center>
  </h3>
  <div>
<input id="search_id" class="search_hide" type="поиск">
<center>
  <h3 id="counter-label">0</h3>
</center>
  </div>
  <center>
<div>
  <form id="click-div">
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">A</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">B</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">C</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">D</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">E</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">T</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">Y</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">U</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-position="">I</div>
  </form>
<button id="reset-button" form="click-div" type="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
  </center>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ОГРОМНОЕ)) Работает как нужно. Сейчас попробую внедрить это в 1с битрикс)

Answer (score 0):

1. Считать надо не клики на чекбокс, а отмеченные чекбоксы.
2. Можно сделать следующим образом.
   (Кстати, буду признателен, если кто-то сможет объяснить, почему вторичная сортировка инпутов по id работает в Firefox, но не работает в Chrome.)

```js
clickHandler = function(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const inputIndex = inputs.indexOf(target);
    counterVal = 0;
    inputs.forEach(inp => counterVal += inp.checked === true); //считаем чекнутые инпуты
    inputs.sort((a, b) => b.id < a.id).sort((a, b) => b.checked - a.checked);
    inputs.forEach(function(inp){
      let copyInp = inp.cloneNode(); //копия инпута
      let text = inp.nextSibling.textContent; // копия текста после инпута
      allInputs.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', copyInp);
      allInputs.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', text);
      inp.nextSibling.remove();
      inp.remove();
      inputs = Array.from(allInputs.querySelectorAll("input"));
      inputs.forEach(inp => inp.addEventListener('click', clickHandler));
    });
  updateDisplay(counterVal);
}


function resetCounter() {
  counterVal = 0;
  updateDisplay(counterVal);
}

function updateDisplay(val) {
  document.getElementById("counter-label").innerHTML = val;
  if (counterVal >= 8) {
    document.getElementById("search_id").style.display = "block";
  } else if (counterVal <= 8) {
    document.getElementById("search_id").style.display = "none";
  }
}

let counterVal = 0;
const allInputs = document.getElementById("all-inputs");
let inputs = Array.from(allInputs.querySelectorAll("input"));
inputs.forEach(inp => inp.addEventListener('click', clickHandler));
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-button");
resetBtn.onclick = resetCounter;
```

```css
.search_id {
            display: none;
            }

            #all-inputs input {
            display: block;
            }

            #all-inputs span {
            display: inline-block;
            }
```

```html
<h3>
            <center>JavaScript Click Counter</center>
          </h3>
          <div>
            <input id="search_id" type="поиск">
            <center>
              <h3 id="counter-label">0</h3>
            </center>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div>
              <div id="all-inputs">
                  <input id='A' type="checkbox">A</input>
                  <input id='B' type="checkbox">B</input>
                  <input id='C' type="checkbox">C</input>
                  <input id='D' type="checkbox">D</input>
                  <input id='E' type="checkbox">E</input>
                  <input id='I' type="checkbox">I</input>
                  <input id='T' type="checkbox">T</input>
                  <input id='U' type="checkbox">U</input>
                  <input id='Y' type="checkbox">Y</input>
                </div>
                
              <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
            </div>
          </center>
```